# rxjs Subject - clear?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I ran through the Tour of Heroes tutorial and changed a bit. I moved the search field to the nav bar. On search, it does a dropdown search:

[image: search bar]

Clicking on any of the `li` in the group will navigate to the detail page of each hero. The issue I am having is that navigation doesn't clear the search term. This is my current function:

```
export class HeroSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Observable<Hero[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
 ...
  gotoDetail(hero: Hero): void {
    let link = ['/detail', hero.id];
    this.router.navigate(link);
  }
```

My thought was that I could call `this.searchTerms.clear()` if such a method existed, but I'm not too familiar with rxjs subjects. I could also reinitialize it:

```
this.searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
```

but wouldn't this create a new object every time I search? What is the best way to solve this?

In addition, I'm not sure that this navigate is working. When I navigate this way, it doesn't seem to use the `@Input()` that is in a sub component.

Edit: deployed on [heroku](http://bs-toh.herokuapp.com/) for people to see the issue. To replicate:

1. go to a 'hero detail' page of hero 11:

   - note the spinning svg. This is the spinner img component. When the img cannot be found (or is loading), it defaults to a spinner img. OnLoad changes the image to the actual image. hero 11 does not have an image, so the spinner stays (desired effect).
2. type "m" in the search bar in the nav.
3. click on Bombasto. Note the pic loads
4. click on Mr. Nice (no pic). Note that there is now no image (although this is hero 11, and we had a spinner before).

Comment: I depends on how and why you're using `Subject`. Can you make a demo with your changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Subject is not storing the value of the search term box, it is just emitting whatever the current value of

```
<input #searchBox>
```

is each time there is a keyup event. A Subject does not store the value of the last emission at all, so if you want to clear the search box it is a matter of setting the value of the input box to ''. eg. in your hero search component add the following property

```
@ViewChild('searchBox') searchBox: ElementRef;
```

then in the gotoDetail method:

```
gotoDetail(hero: Hero): void {
    this.searchBox.nativeElement.value = '';
    let link = ['/detail', hero.id];
    this.router.navigate(link);
}
```

Using a Subject for this is not the recommended way of doing this, but ok for starters. A better way is to create an Observable direct from the keyup event on the DOM element - there is an example of this approach here - https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/autocomplete/autocomplete.js

Comment: The only reason I was using a subject is because of the tutorial. Are you saying that a Subject isn't a great data model in general, or just for this particular use case?

Comment: It is not an issue for a simple starter, no need to worry about it while getting started, but this is a good article about why it is not the best solution for this sort of problem  https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93

Comment: Are there any issues (security or other) with accessing a `nativeElement` like this? I imagine no since I'm setting not getting? In addition, this does seem to clear the text box, but it leaves the dropdown open. Maybe I'll try switching to an observable like you said and see if that fixes it.

Comment: No issues I am aware of with accessing nativeElement like that - it is the recommended way rather than accessing direct with likes of getElementyId. If you also add this.searchTerms.next(''); to the gotoDetail method that should make menu disappear as the emitting empty search term returns an empty heroes []